# How to show a subset is a subspace by representing it as a span of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given that $U \subseteq P_4$ consists of all polynomials of the form $(a+2)x^4 + (a+2b)x^3 - (b-1)x^2 + (2a+b+3)$ and asked to show it's a subspace of $P_4$ by representing it as a span of polynomials.

I rearranged the form to get $a(x^4 + x^3 + 2)+b(2x^3 - x^2 + 1)+(2x^4 + x^2 + 3)$ which suggests two polynomials:  $$x^4 + x^3 + 2$$
$$2x^3 - x^2 + 1$$
but I have no idea how to treat that last one hanging on the end - the original polynomial in this form doesn't make a linear combination of polynomials. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Put $a=a'-2$, $b=b'+1$. As there is no conditions on $a,b$, there is no conditions on $a'$ and $b'$. Rewrite your family of polynomials using $a'$ and $b'$.

Comment: Thank you! The thought crossed my mind to try and 'vanish' those terms and I noted that $b=1$ and $a=-2$ would make the coefficients equal to zero but didn't put this together for some reason.